# Alt+Tab switcher on primary monitor only

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, application-switcher

Is it possible in Ubuntu Unity to show Alt+Tab switcher always on primary monitor instead of where mouse pointer is?

Comment: Mine is showing in the middle. Yours is showing at the pointer's location?

Comment: @Arst It is shown in the center of the monitor where your mouse pointer is.